# How to define a style of element using external CSS in mxGraph?

Tags: javascript, css, mxgraph

I'm trying to create toolbar in mxGraph:

```
let divForToolbar = document.createElement("div");
divForToolbar.classList.add("toolbar")
let toolbar = new mxToolbar(divForToolbar);
```

Then, I import css stylesheet containing class toolbar. But all styles defined in "toolbar" class in it don't work.

Official documentation offers to define styles right in JS code using mxStylesheet and mxConstants, or define inline styles like this:

```
divForToolbar.style.overflow = 'auto';
```

But I suppose that define style in JS is a bad practice. How to define style in external CSS properly?

Comment: Have you investigated why the styles in your stylesheet aren't being applied? Is the stylesheet loading okay? Are the styles being overridden?

Comment: Styles are applied for other elements on same page, like navbar and buttons, but not applied to mxToolbar

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing class names or add a container toolbar(`editor.setToolbarContainer`).
https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/toolbar.html
https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/uiconfig.html

In more complicated issues override `toolbar.addMode` method. It help me create own style toolbar.